# Is merged Zamasu fully immortal in Dragon Ball Heroes?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-manga, dragon-ball-heroes

In Dragon Ball Heroes episode 10 Jiren attacks merged Zamasu with a giant energy ball and merged Zamasu gets out of it unharmed, claiming he's immortal. In Dragon Ball Super, merged Zamasu was half immortal, because he was the fusion of an immortal body with a mortal one, so his right side took harm with Goku's, Trunks' and Vegito's attacks. Is merged Zamasu fully immortal in Dragon Ball Heroes?

Comment: As of now we csn't sau unless further info is given but it is probably best to assume he isn't. During the fight against Goku in the future Merged Zamasu says he is immortal but that is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Dragon Ball Heroes episode 11 , Zamasu states to Jiren he's fully inmortal. (he always is going to be healed he says)